# Making a custom right click menu and binding it to a right click inside of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

Without using long and code resource intensive jQuery and Javascript context menu plugins, how can one, just using plain & simple jQuery code to basically take my div (which has the id: 'right-click-menu') and bind a right click action to the other div which had the id: box1?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ALAHX/

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

#right-click-menu {
    width: 150px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(212,208,200);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(212,208,200);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(64,64,64);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(64,64,64);
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 8.5pt;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(142,142,142);
}
#right-click-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
    background: rgb(212,208,200);

    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px
}
#right-click-menu ul li {
    padding: 4px;
}
#right-click-menu li:hover {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgb(10,36,106);
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="right-click-menu">
        <ul>

            <li>option1</li>
            <li>option2</li>
            <li>option3</li>
            <li>option4</li>        
        </ul>
    </div>
<br>
<div id="box1" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; height: 50px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "just using plain, simple and vanilla jQuery code" ... I sure hope you mean JavaScript and not jQuery.

Comment: I wasn't aware that jQuery had a vanilla... -- it's already a library itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question is tagged JS, but has no JS attempt. Please edit and show us what you have tried before you request code from us.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I am new and not sure where to start coding. I don't want to tack on another plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box1').mouseup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 3) { // right click   
            $('#right-click-menu').offset({ top: event.pageY, left: event.pageX });
        }
    });    
});
```

HTML: Be sure to include `position: absolute` for the menu to allow it to move around, and `oncontextmenu` to return false to prevent the default browser right-click.

```
<div id="right-click-menu" style="position:absolute;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <ul>            
        <li>option1</li>
        <li>option2</li>
        <li>option3</li>
        <li>option4</li>        
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div id="box1" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ALAHX/1/

You'll want to include things like hiding the menu at first and when options are selected, but this should get you started.

Looking at you comment, you may or may not have included jQuery in your project, which is a Javascript addon. The above code is written using jQuery, so make sure to include a `<script>` link to it in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').click(function(){
     $('#box1').slideToggle('slow');
     }); 
});
```

Maybe something like this?